# Creating membership tables online

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership

I want to create the membership tables online that are used for ASP.Net 3.5 login controls.  I thought their was a script I could use or executable on my computer to install those tables.

Is that the case?  or what would be the best method to create the tables online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of scripts for membership and role databases under

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
```

Something like:

```
InstallCommon.sql
InstallMembership.sql
InstallPersistSqlState.sql
InstallPersonalization.sql
InstallProfile.SQL
InstallRoles.sql
InstallSqlState.sql
InstallSqlStateTemplate.sql
InstallWebEventSqlProvider.sql
```

and their equivalent uninstall scripts, too.

The easiest way to install those databases is to use the `aspnet_regsql` command line tool in that directory. It's a wizard that walks you through installing the necessary bits.